# Google map not centered in desired location

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working with Google Maps in an Android application.

I need to center the map in the device´s current position.

I am using the following code to do it:

```
String latitud_usuario = prefs.getString("latitud", "");
String longitud_usuario = prefs.getString("longitud", "");
String username = prefs.getString("username", "");
Log.d("JSON", "spots en home latitud " + latitud_usuario);
Log.d("JSON", "spots en home longitud " + longitud_usuario);
Log.d("JSON", "spots en home username " + username);
LatLng miPosition = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitud_usuario), Double.parseDouble(longitud_usuario));

googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getContext(), R.raw.map_style));
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
change_map_satelite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
change_map_normal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
Marker yo = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(miPosition)
    .title(username)
);
yo.setTag(username);
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(miPosition));
CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);
```

For now, the map shows the current position marker, but not centered in the screen.

I am getting the current position latitude and longitude from sharedpreferences.

Both values are right and verified in the log output:

```
spots en home latitud 41.6352103

spots en home longitud 2.1633905
```

The map screen center is not far away from the desired location, about 10 km north from the desired location.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if the location is valid it's enough to use animate camera:

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(miPosition).zoom(15).build();
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the move Camera like below both `position` and the `zoom`  level in one line . In your case you have move the camera first to the marker location but again you have animate with the zoom. then the position of marker may change as you experienced. use it like below.

```
CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(miPosition, 15);
```

Then you can use either this to `move`

```
googleMap.moveCamera(update);
```

or this to `animate`

```
googleMap.animateCamera(update);
```

Comment: thank you, it works changing CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(miPosition), 15) with CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(miPosition, 15)

Comment: you are welcome and thanks  .. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Move to center as below

```
Projection projection = googleMap.getProjection();
    LatLng markerPosition = marker.getPosition();
    Point markerPoint = projection.toScreenLocation(markerPosition);
    Point targetPoint = new Point(markerPoint.x, markerPoint.y - view.getHeight() / 2);
    LatLng targetPosition = projection.fromScreenLocation(targetPoint);
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(targetPosition), 1000, null);
```

Comment: not working, and the zoom factor is not taken into account